# How to limit a typescript generic to one of two primitives?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am writing a function that runs through a list of parameters looking for elements. If found, the function strips the name and returns the value, and if not there, a default. The values will be either a `number` or `string`. I would like a way to use the typescript generics, and the constraints to get the following to compile.

```
function GetValue<T extends number | string>(datum: string, element: string, defaultValue: T): T {
    if (datum.startsWith(element)) {
        if (typeof defaultValue === 'number')
            return parseInt(datum.substring(element.length)); // error
        else if (typeof defaultValue === 'string')
            return datum.substring(element.length); // error
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

I've excluded any error checking code, e.g. from the `parseInt`. This would be called as;

```
console.log(GetValue("abc123", "abc", 456));
console.log(GetValue("abc123", "def", 456));
```

And expect to get out `123` and `456`.

Currently, it fails on the lines `// error` since the function could be called with a type that is extends a `string` or `number` but is not a `string` or `number`.

How do I constrain the generic `T` such that it is limited to be either a `string` or `number` (and not the union `string | number`) and the return type is then matched to the type of the `defaultValue`?

Comment: What types do you plan to pass that extend a number or a string? I don't get it.

Comment: None, only string and number, the compiler just recognises that it could be called with such a type and gives an error; ts(2322)

Comment: So why don't you do for instance `GetValue(datum: string, element: string, defaultValue: number | string): number | string`?

Comment: The resultant type in `const V = GetValue("abc", "a", "DEF")` would be `string | number`, I would want it to be just a `string` or `number`

Comment: This function isn't safe... TS says `GetValue<123>("a", "a", 123)` returns `123`, but it does not.

Comment: @Gerrit0. Correct, I wouldn't expect that call to work, the MCVE excludes error checking, I've updated to include how I would expect to be called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cast explicit to T, to remove this error

```
function GetValue<T extends number | string>(datum: string, element: string, defaultValue: T): T {
    if (datum.startsWith(element)) {
        if (typeof defaultValue === 'number')
            return parseInt(datum.substring(element.length)) as T;
        else if (typeof defaultValue === 'string')
            return datum.substring(element.length) as T;
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

There is an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35858) open on github which discusses this topic.

Comment: So, it looks like there is no way to explicitly limit the generic to one of two (or a few) types, other that to say it satisfies the requirements of the type. The cast works, so I'll keep going with that for now.

Comment: What do you mean with 'no way to limit the generic'? Inside the T constraint you specified that it can be only a number or string with the union number | string.

Comment: Ok, I think see the origin of the bug/design limitation. It can't see that the "base" would need to be a primitive, it only sees the "extend", hence asserts a derived type could be used.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at other approach:

```js
interface Overloading {
  <T extends number>(datum: string, element: string, defaultValue: T): number;
  <T extends string>(datum: string, element: string, defaultValue: T): string;
}

const GetValue: Overloading = <T extends number | string>(datum: string, element: string, defaultValue: T) => {
  if (datum.startsWith(element)) {
    if (typeof defaultValue === 'number')
      return parseInt(datum.substring(element.length));
    else if (typeof defaultValue === 'string')
      return datum.substring(element.length);
  }
  return defaultValue;
}



const res = GetValue('12', 'sdf', 2) // number
const res = GetValue('12', 'sdf', 'sdf') // string
const res = GetValue('12', 'sdf', ()=>{}) // error
```

Sometimes it is better to not define explicitly return type of function. Let TS do it for you.

I have used this function overloading for constraints.

**UPDATE**

TS docs: [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)

```js
//Let's say you have an enum:

const enum State {
  idle = 'idle',
  active = 'active',
  disable = 'disable'
}
//And you have a function:
// function handleState(state: State, payload: string | number | number[]): void;

// But you have next constraints:
// If state is `active`, payload should be only string
// If state is `idle`, payload should be number
// If state is `disable`, payload shoul be array of numbers number[]
// So let's update our handleState function
function handleState(state: State.active, payload: string): void;
function handleState(state: State.idle, payload: number): void;
function handleState(state: State.disable, payload: number[]): void;
function handleState(state: State, payload: string | number | number[]) {}

handleState(State.active, 2) // Error, active state can't be along with number payload
handleState(State.active, '2') // Ok, active state can be along with string payload
```

To make overloads for arrow functions, please consider interfaces, just like in my first example.

You can add to overloadings generic parameters, like I did.

Is that what you are asking about?

Because in case with generics:

```js
interface Overloading {
  <T extends number>(datum: string, element: string, defaultValue: T): number
  <T extends string>(datum: string, element: string, defaultValue: T): string
}
```

T is either number or string, but not the union one.

Comment: This looks interesting. Could you please expand on what how this works; the `Overloading` interface?

Comment: Thanks, I get where this going. I think, although maybe more complex than I want for this particular problem, I will find useful in other areas.

Comment: I use overloads for event handlers. For example for SocketIO lib.